# Remove App ID with free Apple Developer Account

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle-identifier

Apple recently introduced the Free Provisioning in iOS9 & Xcode 7. I was using it and XCode registered my bundle ID automatically as an App ID, now I want to remove the App ID to use it with another account but I can't find the way to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete an App ID associated with a Personal Team?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34552441/how-to-delete-an-app-id-associated-with-a-personal-team)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't manage AppIDs and provisioning profiles created by Free Account.
If you want to revoke AppID, send email or call to apple support.

Email 
https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit/

Call
https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.php

It will take few minites or hours.

Comment: Omg, this is absolutely terrible. Apple really makes it incredibly hard to publish an app: DUNS, then account approval, then payment approval and now this. It's been 20 days already and we haven't even started submitting the app. On Google Play the whole process took 15min.

Comment: Sharing my experience: I contacted Apple support by email. It tooks within a week to revoke the App ID and reuse it with another account.

Comment: Phone call is much faster than email. Call to apple instead of sending email, if you don't want to wait long time.

Answer (score 0):

May be there is no manage option for free account. Because, I did not find  any option to add any device,create app ID, downloading provisioning and distribution profile from free account.

For free account you will not find **Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles**

Comment: if there is no manage option how can a free user remove an App ID? XCode registered it automatically...

Comment: i could not find any option to remove.

Comment: this free option  can only do all automatically

Comment: you need not remove app ID, but create new one (also automatically).

Comment: additionally,  you will not able your app up to app store, this this is only for testing

Comment: but my bundle id will be locked forever?

Comment: if you pay $99, it will be automatically activated for all

Comment: I have a developer account with another email but it says that the bundle id is already in use.

Comment: Same problem here, do you find a solution?

Comment: I have come across this too, and I have just emailed Apple explaining everything to them. Hopefully they will get back to me about it and I can update this post.

Comment: @user1898712 so?

Comment: @Zotyi - They got back to me, and they had to disassociate my app from my free account and associate it with my paid account. Nightmare, but hey, a simple email sorted it for me.