# How to delete an App ID associated with a Personal Team?

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

[Ever since WWDC 2015](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2933052/apple-frees-casual-ios-developers-of-membership-requirement.html), developers now have a **Personal Team** in addition to the other teams they are members of.

My account is part of an organization as well, so when I go to my Accounts in Xcode, I see something like so under Team Names:

- *Organization*, Agent, Agent
- *User* (Personal Team), Free, Free

I accidentally created an app identifier using the "Fix It" button in Xcode using the wrong team (personal team instead of the organization). Now if I attempt to register that App ID for my organization, it [complains that it is already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20565565/35690):

> Failed to register bundle identifier. The app identifier "..." cannot be registered to your development team because it is not available. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.

Normally this can easily be resolved via logging in to https://developer.apple.com, navigating to your App IDs, and then deleting them. However, I can only access App IDs for my organization rather than my Personal Team. Typically if you are a member of multiple teams, it allows you to choose which team to manage. However, the Personal Team never appears as an option.

If I double click my personal team in Xcode, I do indeed see a provisioning profile for the App ID in question. I cannot figure out how to see these provisioning profiles on https://developer.apple.com.

**How do I delete an App ID associated with a Personal Team that I no longer need?**

Either via:

- Logging in to https://developer.apple.com and managing App IDs, provisioning profiles, etc. (for a **Personal Team**); or
- Xcode (if there is no way to do it on the developer portal).

---

**Update:** It appears that free accounts have the same problem. If I try to create a new Apple ID and log in to the developer portal, I see a severely striped down version. The top menu just shows *Home*, *Programs & Add-ons*, and *Your Account*. There is no way to access the iOS features such as Provisioning Profiles, App ID, etc. unless I pay the yearly developer fee. But even then, I would likely only see the App IDs for my new organization, not my Personal Team.

Comment: I'm guessing that you've already tried logging out and back in? That's when you get to choose which team you want to go into the dev portal as. Choosing the personal team _should_ get you to the right App IDs list where you can delete it.

Comment: @AllenZeng: Yup, I just updated the question with the things I have tried.

Comment: Don't know then :/ The only viable avenue I can see is contacting Apple. You have my condolences for clicking on the "Fix Issue" button. Here's a tool that may save you from it in the future: https://github.com/neonichu/FixCode

Comment: any news on this issue?

Comment: This is crazy. I did the same thing. I tried to solve it by enrolling to the developer program on my personal account with the hope that I could go in and delete the app id - the list was empty though! Now I'm looking for some sort of support contact form to Apple, they've hidden it well...

Answer (score 30):

There is a way to sort this out. Contact the [**Apple Developer Program Support**](https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone/) and they can help you delete the App ID from your free provisioning profile (you can't do it yourself at the moment). I just did this and I would recommend contacting them by phone since you will need to get past the first-line support to a Senior Advisor in order to fix this. First-line support did not understand what I was talking about.

Comment: This worked! I had the same problem: first-line support didn't understand, but the Senior Advisor (Katy) was very helpful. She acknowledged that I had no way to remove it myself and she was able to delete the App ID.

Perhaps the clearest way to communicate the problem is to give them the short URL of this SO post!

Comment: Is there still no better way of doing this?

Comment: You saved my day! I recommend contact by phone!

Comment: yeah, only way to solve is to call Apple. in my case the very nice rep spoke to senior support for me and had them remove the id from the wrong account. took about 10min

Comment: This saved me so much time. Thank you! They are really easy to work with over the phone as well.

Answer (score 9):

You can also submit a request via **Apple Developer Program Support**
https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit/. The support team removed my personal team AppID within 24 hours, very efficient.
[image]

Comment: sent an email and they removed in less than 1 hour, thanks a lot

Comment: I can confirm this solution works. They removed my Personal Team bundle ID do I could register it again. The whole process took 24h.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was very frustrating! (been struggling for hours with this). I thought I had done exactly what you did above with the Fix it button and set the App Name to my "Personal Team"!? and I had no way of setting the app name up in iTunes Connect on the correct account (as I was getting the warning message "The App Name you entered has already been used".

One alternative I wasn't aware of is when you create a new App Name in iTunes Connect you need to set the Primary Language.

I was selecting "English" and there is another option for "UK English" which I needed! There are multiple English languages to choose from.

Hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score -2):

1. Log in to the iOS developer member center and navigate to "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles".
2. Once in there, navigate into the App IDs section inside of the Identifiers section.
3. Create a new App ID with the same wildcard bundle ID you are already using but using your Team ID based prefix as its prefix. By doing so, you will be associating your wildcard bundle ID with a new Team ID. It is okay to leave your old App ID associated with your wildcard bundle ID there and not delete it - it will be ignored going forward.
4. Edit all your provisioning profiles that are associated to the old App ID and update them to use the new App ID.
5. Go into all of the provisioning profiles that you have changed and regenerate them
6. Re-archive your app. Then, submit your new archive making sure to sign it with your new Team ID prefix based provisioning profile.

Source: [Steps to move an App ID from a non-Team ID prefix to the Team ID](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2311/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014135-CH1-STEPS_TO_MOVE_AN_APP_ID_FROM_A_NON_TEAM_ID_PREFIX_TO_THE_TEAM_ID)

**Resume**: Just create a wild card with your new Team and your App ID created with Personal Team will be ignored.