# How to remove iOS Team Provisioning Profile / AppID on Xcode?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos, cordova

I am new to Mac and I have to use it for developing Ionic hybrid app for iOS. I am using Mac 10.11 with Xcode 7.

Now, I have get my app ready and want to deploy it to app store. But I am having trouble with the App ID. In my Xcode, when I go to account, I can see Team Name list with 2 items. One is my name with Agent for iOS and Mac. The other one is my name (Personal Team) with Free for iOS and Mac.

The problem is in the Personal Team item, I have the provisioning profiles with the app ID I want to use for deploy into app store. Since it is already in here, I can’t create that app ID again in my developer account. I tried but I can’t find a way to remove it.

So, how can I remove that app ID / Provisioning Profile so that I can use it in my developer account?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete an App ID associated with a Personal Team?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34552441/how-to-delete-an-app-id-associated-with-a-personal-team)

Answer (score 8):

The only way I manage to do that is to contact the customer support (Apple Developer Program Support), after few days and few back and forth they finally deleted the bundle id from my Personal Team and I was able to add it to my Developer Program (Agent) profile. I know this is not ideal but at least if you really want to use the same Bundle ID it worked for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12216429)

Comment: @AleksanderAzizi why this does not provide an answer? This is the only way currently to achieve what was asked.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether. http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: The question was:
So, how can I remove that app ID / Provisioning Profile so that I can use it in my developer account?

The answer is:
Contact Apple Developer Program Support as they are the only one that have access to make this change.

I struggle to understand why this is not an answer but anyhow.

Comment: I can confirm that having had an App-ID inadvertently added by a team member's Xcode to his free/personal team account, the only way to have it deleted was to call Apple Dev Support. It took a few days and several very detailed emails explaining the visible issue ("App-ID not available" error) to get someone to finally understand what the problem was, and have the App-ID removed. Also, due to Apple's privacy policies, they won't tell you which account has the App-ID registered, but instead they'll send an email to said account and wait for a response before taking any further action.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with *App ID* but **Bundle ID** that is unique in the AppStore.

Currently, you **can't** 'restore' Bundle ID in any way.
You **can** create another App ID with the same *Name* but **different** Bundle ID.

**Solution**: go to your other Developer Program, create new App, choose slight different Bundle ID and you are good to go.

Reference:
[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering my question. I want to keep the app ID (com.companyname.appname) to be same with my android app, I don't want to create a different one for iOS. Currently the problem is because it is used in the Xcode in the FREE "account". How can I delete it so that I can create it again in the agent account (developer account) from the website?

Comment: I work as iOS Developer for 4 years, mostly in Software Development Houses so I've done it multiple times for multiple clients.

There is simply **no** way to do this - so you need to create App ID with new **Bundle** like this: com1.companyname.appname - please remember that this is **not** visible to anyone on client side - this is just for Xcode / programmers.
You can keep the same **Name** in the App ID, so if your application was named 'My awesome app' it can still be like this, but you can't bypass the fact that you **need** to create new Bundle ID - no way to delete it, trust me.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So, what is the difference between App ID and the Bundle ID? Do you mean that the bundle ID has to be different (like com1.companyname.appname) and I can still keep the App ID to be (com.companyname.appname)? Is that mean in my config.xml, I can still keep the id to be (com.companyname.appname)?

Comment: App ID consists of 2 elements - *Name* and *Bundle ID*. You can use same *Name* in number of applications, but *Bundle ID* must be **unique**.

So, the App ID is always unique -> com1.companyname.appname.

Another thing that you can do, you can upload application from your account with proper App ID to iTunesConnect and there you can transfer it to another team, here is official doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/10_ManagingYourApplications/ManagingYourApplications.html

Answer (score 0):

You can select your **App ID** in the Developer portal under [iOS App IDs](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/bundle) to edit and delete.

If you're referring to your [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/) listing, you cannot remove your application listing. You *can* however use a different **Bundle ID** with the same **App ID**. Which, in turn, would solve your problem.

As for **Provisioning profiles**, you can edit and remove them in the [Provisioning Portal](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/).

[@Alexandros Trepeklis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3841493/alexandros-trepeklis) suggested contacting [Apple Developer Program Support](https://developer.apple.com/support/membership/); they may be able to help you remove the original app listing.

And as [@Krodak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/982550/krodak) mentioned, you should read ['s documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html) on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** delete an **App ID and Bundle ID** on your own through the developer portal **if you have not yet posted the app to iTunes Connect**. The TL;DR is that you need to add a capability to your app to force Xcode to generate an explicit listing for your app on the portal. Once the listing is there, you can remove it (and all associated provisioning profiles and whatnots).

**Step by step:**

1. Add a capability, say push notifications, to your app.

[image: Go to the capabilities tab]

[image: Add a capability]

[image: Adding entitlement]

2. Now log in to the [developer portal](https://developer.apple.com/). Go to Account > Certificates, IDs, & Profiles > App IDs. You should see the App ID prefixed with "XC"

[image: App ID listing on portal]

3. Click on the App ID you want to delete and then click the Edit button.

[image: Click on App ID then edit]

4. Click Delete towards the bottom of the listing.

[image: Click Delete]

5. Confirm the delete. This should free up the App ID and Bundle ID for use with another team.

[image: Confirm delete]