# The app ID cannot be registered to your development team

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

I am trying to deploy an iOS app to a test device with Xcode 9.1. but I get the following error:

```
The app ID "com.myDomain.myApp" cannot be registered to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.
```

I have 2 Apple IDs registered in Xcode and I made the mistake of choosing "Automatically manage signing" with the wrong development team, the one associated to the wrong Apple Id. Now I want to change it but I don't know how.

This is what the signing section of the target looks like for the development team I chose by mistake:

[image]

This is what the signing section of the target looks like for the development team I would like to use instead:

[image]

I have gone to the Apple Developer portal and couldn't find the app under App IDs, so I don't know how I can remove it to start from scratch. I have removed the signing certificate from the local keychain but that is not enough.

Note that I still would like to use "Automatically manage signing" and I would still like to keep the bundle identifier.

Comment: It's telling you to change the bundle identifier though (eg."com.myDomain.myApp"), which is in use by something or someone else.

Comment: I don't want to change the bundle id, I want to undo the provisioning done on the wrong dev team, so that I can redo it on the right dev team, with the same bundle id, as stated in the question.

Comment: Then untick the "Automatically manage signing" option and do it manually...

Comment: I would like to still use "automatic manage signing", as stated in the question. There must be a way to invalidate the wrong provisioning and that is what I am asking about.

Comment: You'll probably need to go into the Apple developer portal and invalidate it there.

Comment: @atineoSE have you managed to invalidate the wrong provisioning?

Comment: @oluckyman no, it looks like contacting support is the only option so far according to solutions posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34552441/how-to-manage-personal-team-info-on-apple-developer-website

Comment: Is it not a case of removing the app Id from team 1 so that it is free to be registered by Xcode to team 2?

Comment: @GMan the whole point of the question is to be able to have the same App Id

Comment: @atineoSE so you want to have an app Id associated with your personal team and a paid/production account team? I can understand why that is not possible. I have a similar problem. My app Id is associated with my personal team and not the paid/production team.

Comment: Hello @atineoSE not really an answer but how did you fixed it ?

Comment: @DexSebas try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37297935

Comment: Thanks man ! I will contact them.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I *had* to reuse the Bundle Identifier, because we were replacing an old app. I spent three hours trying everything I could find on the internet.

In the end I changed the bundle identifier, pressed all the buttons, *then* changed it back to the original bundle identifier and everything worked.

This is not the first time that I spent hours wasting in Xcode/ iOS Dev while in the end I just needed to do some voodoo ritual.

Comment: Do you remember what "all the buttons" was, more or less?

Comment: Not really - I think I changed everything so that it fully compiled and I could run it on my phone, and then put it back on the old identifier

Comment: really ?! having the same problem too right now... Will try your advice. lol

Comment: this worked like magic!  I just added ".staging" to the end of my bundle identifier, then ran it, it worked, I changed it back to the original bundle identifier, deleted the app on my device, cleaned the device and when I built it again it worked!  ------------Would also recommend making sure you are on the right dev team, though it sounds like that's not the OP's problem, it is something that xcode may default you wrongly, or that you may change absentmindedly when debugging otherwise

Answer (score 7):

Change the app Bundle Identifier and make sure its unique.
For example: **com.companyname.appname** to **com.companyname.appname123**

Answer (score 1):

Change bundle identifier to all lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked in my case (I needed to keep the same bundle ID as the app exists on the AppStore, clearing everything and changing the bundle ID to something different, then back to original did not work).

- Selecting 'Debug' in signing and capabilities for the target, and set the correct team. For some reason the selected team was the old one there even tho it was updated in 'all'