# How to remove Bundle identifier from Personal Account and add to the Developer portal

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, app-store-connect

[image]

**Here is the scenerio**
i had added bundle identifier in xcode and entered my apple account(when it was not paid account) its bad i bought developer account now my account shows another account,
One is my personal account and the other is team account,
Now when I go to developer account and enter that bundle id, it appears, this bundle id is not available.
I want to removed bundle identifier from my personal account and want to add to the developer portal

Comment: You can't.  It's gone. Pick another bundle id and move on

Comment: Contact Apple they can transfer it over. There are disadvantages of doing this so make sure you do research about the consequences of transferring apps. It would be better if you just upgrade your regular account to a business account then you can just add/remove emails.

Comment: I resolve this issue by talking apple Support , He remove My bundle identifier from personal account within 2 minutes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete an App ID associated with a Personal Team?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34552441/how-to-delete-an-app-id-associated-with-a-personal-team)